# Opening/Reading 2 types of files

Tags: php, file-handling

The blog that I am creating creates a file for the "Title" of the blog post and another file for the actual blog "entry" and then saves these files in a folder called "ent"

Im trying to display the Title and then the entry text should go below it. With the code I have so far it displays all titles, but under each title it displays only 1 text entry and its the same one.
I also need to order it so the most latest entry appears at the top, but im not sure how I would do that.

Help would much be appreciated!!! <3

My code is below:

```
$titlecount = 0;
$textcount = 0;
foreach(glob("ent/title*.txt") as $title){
    $titlecount++;
    $title_handle=fopen($title,"r");
    while(!feof($title_handle)){
        $title =fgets($title_handle);
        echo "<h2 align='center'>$title</h2>";
        echo"<h1 align='right'>$titlecount</h1>";
    }
    foreach (glob("ent/text*.txt") as $file) {

        if($textcount<$titlecount){
            $file_handle = fopen($file, "r");
            while (!feof($file_handle)) {
                $line = fgets($file_handle);
                $textcount++;
                echo "<p align='center'>$line</p>";
                echo"<p align='right'>$textcount</p>";
            }
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the blog entry located?

Comment: Both the blog entries and title txt files are stored using this code:

Comment: The blog entry txt files are located in the ent directory along with the blog title txt files. They are just named differently when created. The blog entry file names start with "text" + date the file is created, the blog file names start with "title"+date the file is created

Comment: Unless you created those dates on the Server, which could also be a problem with multiple files being created with your system at the same time, I would rename those files... Better yet, use a MySQL Database to store data... It makes more sense.